# Copy & Paste Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a simple dice roller in Google sheets for a gaming group I am part of.

I've got this so far.

```
function RollDice20() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('intDiceRollMain20').setValue('=RANDBETWEEN(1,20)');
}
```

The trouble is with this, that RANDBETWEEN will change every time a cell is altered afterwards.  I'd like to be able do two additional steps:-

1. Copy the value of intDiceRollMain20.
2. Paste the value only of intDiceRollMain20 into intDiceRollFixed20.
3. Clear the contents of intDiceRollMain20.

Would anyone be able to help with this?